# How do I increase the font size/color of the Android Monitor

Tags: android, android-studio

Found plenty of info on how to change the size of the editors, but nothing about the tiny font within the Android **Monitor**, any pointers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it, wasn't so hard after all ...

[image]